# Searching elements of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, `A = [22,33,22,33]` and `B = [3,10,5,9]`.

I want to create a new array like this `C = [22,max(3,5), 33, max(10,9)]`

Could someone help! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What’s the logic for picking those?

Comment: does both the arrays will be of same size always and you want to take maximum at those two specific points always?

Comment: When findingequal elmnts in the array A go and search in the the array B the max corresponding to these elmts

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Yes the same size

Comment: `[].concat(...Object.entries(B.reduce((a,i,n)=>((a[A[n]]=(a[A[n]]!==undefined)?Math.max(a[A[n]],i):i),a),{}))).map(Number);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group by the values of array `a` and take the values of `b` at the same index of `a` for grouping.

```js
var a = [22, 33, 22, 33],
    b = [3, 10, 5, 9],
    groups = new Map(),
    result;
    
a.forEach(g => groups.set(g, -Infinity)); // prevent zero false values
b.forEach((v, i) => groups.set(a[i], Math.max(groups.get(a[i]), v)));
result = [].concat(...groups);

console.log(result);
```